# How to allow other security group on security group inbound http

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have two security group.

1. SG-1
2. SG-2

I want to allow http port only security group.
I try to add SG-2 on inbound http rules of SG-1.

But this not working.

I try to access private ip and also not working.

How to add other security group on http?

Comment: You need to provide exact setup of your SGs, NACLs. Otherwise, its difficult to speculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I use 172.31.0.0/16, allowd source in my security group http policy.